# How to calculate position of edge circle and rotation to center

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, trigonometry

i have mathematical formula and i have spawn points. but, i have so differenet object sizes and radiuses. how i can instantiate a objects in the edge of circle and rotate them onto center circle like picture;
i am bad with this stuf and my code is wrong or not i dont know

````
```
 public void GetObstacle(int count, CircleRotator rotator)
 {
    float TAU = 6.283185307179586f;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Transform cameraTR = mainCamera.transform;
        Transform tr = rotator.transform;
        var obj = new GameObject();

        float t = (float)i / count;
        float angle = t * TAU * 0.25f; //
        Vector3 itemCenter = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle) * rotator.GetRadius + tr.position.x,
           tr.position.y + Mathf.Sin(angle) * rotator.GetRadius);
        obj.transform.position = itemCenter;
        Vector3 current = tr.position - cameraTR.position;
        Vector3 target = obj.transform.position - cameraTR.position;
        obj.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Vector3.Dot(current, target));

        obj.transform.SetParent(tr);
    }
 }
```
````

where 0.25 in here i dont understand. But without 0.25 all will broke. angle = t * TAU * 0.25f;

help pls or give some adwice. https://ibb.co/qNhZCh3 what i would like but what i have https://ibb.co/NFSRmSn

so many formulas and watched videos. but i can't understand how

Comment: Havent gone through the math yet but right away i notice you're feeding a value that isnt in degrees (the result of a dot product) to a method that's expecting a value in degrees (2nd argument of `Rotate`). Maybe you mean `obj.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Mathf.Acos(Vector3.Dot(current, target)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);`

Comment: It's a little unclear what the local axes of the objects are but maybe `obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, itemCenter - tr.position);` will help?

Comment: @Ruzihm your code work but like it half circle because if i have spawn object in bottom circle for example angle = 53 but must -53. This answer for first post

Comment: @Ruzihm you are my hero ! Second post save me thanks! But second question is alive. how spawn object not in the center of the border, but from the outside. i cant add half size onto position because this a circle? correct?

Comment: try `obj.transform.position = itemCenter; obj.transform.rotation = ...; obj.transform.Translate(0f,rotator.GetRadius,0f);`

Comment: @Ruzihm no doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ruzihm with help rotations.
spawn outside edge I got this way, where I'm not sure if this is the right way, where Size is the size of y collider. If someone show another good way i will be gratitude!

```
Vector3 direction = (tr.position - obj.transform.position);
        obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, direction);
        obj.transform.position -= direction.normalized * obj.Size()/2f;
```